# How to dynamically create a new file that should be included in the bundle with webpack?

Tags: webpack

I want to modify my webpack config with a custom middleware or loader that helps me by:

- Finding all `src/**/*.srv.js`
- Creating or updating a file that:

  - Imports them
  - Exports them in an object
    ( export default { x, y, z, etc } )
  - Include new file in bundle so I can easily use them in `main.js`

This is a simplified usecase of what I actually need, but if I know how to do this, I can solve the rest myself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with a solution that I suppose is good enough.

First I clean/create a file through a plugin that is run on script startup. Then I found out that loaders can see the filepath of the current processing file with `this.resourcePath`, so I just let a loader in preload insert import/export statements into the new file I just created.

This file is included in my main. Works like a charm. ...but its not strictly in memory and it doesnt handle removed/renamed files. But close enough!

Example code here:
https://github.com/presidenten/vuex-automator-loader

Answer (score 3):

this is SUPER late but in case anybody else lands here, I think the best way to solve this would be to generate a separate asset for every `srv.js` file, which can be done with a simple loader [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57617060/webpack-loaders-create-and-write-files-inside-loader). You can then use these assets in your html just like you would include any other css or js file.

However, if you really want to only generate a single asset, you can do it like so:

1. create a plugin that injects a function to the loader context, so the loaders can pass info back to the plugin ([more info](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2564#issuecomment-222328920))
2. create a loader for `srv.js` files that extracts the data and passes it to the plugin from step 1
3. using the same plugin from step 1, aggregate all the data from the loaders and generates a single asset file ([more info](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1175#issuecomment-116121089))

some rough code to show what I mean:

**Plugin**

```js
class MyPlugin {
    apply(compiler) {
        var allData = "";

        // inject a function to loaderContext so loaders can pass back info
        compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('MyPlugin', compilation =>
            compilation.hooks.normalModuleLoader.tap(
                'MyPlugin',
                (loaderContext, module) => {
                    loaderContext.myExportFn = (data) => {
                        allData += data;
                    }
                }
            )
        );

        // at the end, generate an asset using the data
        compiler.hooks.emit.tapAsync(
            'MyPlugin',
            (compilation, callback) => {
                compilation.assets['myfile.js'] = {
                    source: () => allData,
                    size: () => allData.length
                };
                callback();
            }
        );
    }
}
```

**Loader**

```js
module.exports = function(content) {
    // use the injected function, pass back some data
    this.myExportFn(`loader called for filepath: ${this.resourcePath}`);
    return content; // return the source file unchanged
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a *webpack* way to do what you're describing. However, it seems like you can do that easily via a shell script, possibly using an npm script.

I have a similar use case at work: we use [font-custom](https://github.com/FontCustom/fontcustom) to generate Sass mixins into a (`.gitignore`'d file) `_generated-font.scss` file (from a directory of SVG files) and then import `_generated-font.scss` from a versioned Sass file, which is then picked up by webpack's sass-loader.

This obviously has to happen before webpack is run, so we run it via a `prestart` npm script.

I hope I'm clear enough - let me know otherwise :).