# Webpack Loaders - create and write files inside loader

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-loader

Pretty much what the title suggests. I want to create a metadata file alongside every javascript file in my project. So I need a webpack loader that doesn't change the content at all, and just extracts some metadata and writes it to a file. What's the best way to do this? `fs.writeFileSync` seems to work fine, but I don't know if I should use it since it seems like [some webpack guides](https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-loader/#testing) recommend using something called [`memory-fs`](https://github.com/webpack/memory-fs), webpack's in-memory filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

So this took a while to find and seems rarely mentioned, but webpack loaders actually have a method [`this.emitFile`](https://webpack.js.org/api/loaders/#thisemitfile) specifically for this purpose. Here is some example usage:

```js
function extractMeta(content) {
    // extract and return metadata for file
}

module.exports = function(content) {
    console.log('extracting metadata and writing to file');

    // get source filename, strip file extension and append ".meta"
    const filename = this.resourcePath.split('/').pop().split('.')[0] + '.meta'

    this.emitFile(filename, extractMeta(content));
    return content; // return the source file unchanged
};
```

Comment: So what is the different between `fs.writeFileSync` and `this.emitFIle` ?

Comment: @Does It won't be overwritten if you set up Webpack to clean up the dist folder on every build. Also, it has a context of the dist folder, so you worry less about the correct filepath